# Como colocar border-radius em um span para a toda a linha mesmo onde houver quebra?

Tags: css, css3

**CSS:**

```
.mark-style {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, rgb(183, 202, 88) 50%);
    background-size: 200% 90%;
    font-size: inherit;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: -100% 30%;
    transition: background-position 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.container {
    width: 250px;
    line-height: 2em;

}
```

**Texto de exemplo:**

```
<div class="container">

   Nonnono nono 
         <span class="mark-style">
            nonono nono nonono nonono
            nonono nononono nononno nono 
           <br>
            nonono nono nonono nonoonono
         </span>
           no onno nono. No noonno nonono nonono.

</div>
```

Como faço **no CSS** para que todas as linhas que tiver a classe tenha o `border-radius: 10px;`, veja que eu não posso criar spans separados?

O texto atualmente está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando coloco border-radius, ele fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas gostaria que ficasse assim, é possível fazer isso no CSS?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só com CSS não vai dar... além disso, particularmente, achei que fica estranho, fica parecendo que são duas seleções independentes, e não que é uma coisa contínua fazendo parte de uma só sentença...

Comment: Eu concordo com vc, mas eu não sou o cara do design, eu só estou seguindo o layout que me passaram, se eu não me engano, o pdf faz isso quando vc seleciona um texto. Mas este exemplo é só para entender a pergunta, no caso, os cantos arredondados vão ser menores. A ideia é que pareça uma caneta de marcar.